# Angular 6: Creating a form from a model class

Tags: angular, forms, model

I'm working on an Angular 6 app that will connect to .Net Web Api backend for data manipulation and I'll have some Angular model classes (model) that will represent each table of the database and I'd like to be able to create a form using that model classes.

Let's see some code example: this is how I'm currently creating my form in onInit.

```
createForm() {
    this.vacancyForm = new FormGroup({
      number: new FormControl(),
      requester: new FormControl(),
      date: new FormControl(),
      position: new FormControl(),
      replacement: new FormControl(),
      discharge_date: new FormControl(),
      candidate: new FormControl(),
      contract_type: new FormControl(),
      working_day: new FormControl(),
      annual_salary: new FormControl(),
      business_division: new FormControl(),
      company: new FormControl(),
      workplace: new FormControl(),
      personal_division: new FormControl(),
      department: new FormControl(),
      cost_center: new FormControl(),
      workplace_address: new FormControl()
    });
  }
```

And it works fine, but this vacancy form represents one table in my database and what I'd like to do is to have a typescript class Vacancy with all these properties and to instantiate the form in a way similar to this:

Class Vacancy (vacancy.ts):

```
export class Vacancy {

  number: number
  date: Date
  requester: string
  ...
  constructor(  ) { }
}
```

Class vacancy-form (vacancy-form.component.ts)

```
var _vacancy = new Vacancy();
this.vacancyForm = new FormGroup(_vacancy); // => let's say, the definition of the form is taken from the class fields.
```

I don't know if that makes sense or if that is the way Angular works (or can work) but imagine some field (or fields) change in your table then you'll have to modify not only the model class but also the form definition and I'd like them to be binded (linked or however it should be called) so you only modify model and form takes that model as input definition.

Is that possible?

I'd add that I'm not looking for a way to iterate over a class properties and then through a loop create the form definition, not exactly that (anyway I would consider it if it worth) but a built-in way to link a form definition to a class properties.

Many thanks.

Comment: hi, did you find answer to your question?

Comment: Hello @qwerty, you have an answer in this same thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52663579/2807741

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, inclues all your properties in an array like this :

```
vacancyProperties: string[] = {
    'number',
    'requester',
    'date',
    ...
    'workplace_address'
}
```

After, you can create your from group iterating on `vacancyProperty` array.

```
const group = {}
vacancyProperties.forEach(property => group[property] = new FormControl());
this.vacancyGroup = new FormGroup(group);
```

You have to note that `group[property]` create a field `property` in your object.
For exemple, if `property = 'date'`, it will create

```
{
    ....
    date: new FormControl()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @ghuntheur. Your idea is good and although is not exactly what I'm looking for I will consider it because it's close.
I'd like to have a class that is a representation of a table (a model the same .Net has) and link form definition to that class (model) properties.
You example is not exactly that but its kinda close, but you are creating an array of a fixed type, and what if number is not a string but it should be a Number, and date, what if I would like to define it as Date?
Anyway, I'll try your suggestion and see.

Comment: Dissociate formGroup key fields and type of data returned by your database. All your keys in formGroup are strings. You can create interface that gathers all properties and types

Answer (score 0):

```
The easiest way to create form from the model is using a FormBuilder.

Step 1: Create an object of FormBuilder.
Step 2: Create an object of your model. You can also assign the values to your model.
Step 3: Group your model object using formBuilder object.

Example:

var formBuilder = new FormBuilder();
var vacancyModel = new Vacancy();

var formGroup = formBuilder.group(vacancyModel);

And BOOM.... Your form is ready to use.

The formGroup will have the control name same as property of Vacancy and if the values are assigned to the vacancyModel then the corresponding values will be assigned to the controls.
```